# How to speed up query in sql with over 20 million rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with more than 20 million rows in SQL. Data gets stored from multiple locations in this table. I have to run a query on date. I cannot use any filters as I have to showcase data location wise. It takes more than 30 minutes to run data from a single table. How can I manage it?
I tried indexing also but it doesn't make any difference

```
--  declare @DateTo as DateTime ='2018-08-01';

select distinct 
     [Location Code]
    ,[Bin Code]
    ,[Item No_]
    ,[Quantity]
    ,[Qty_ (Base)]
    ,[Zone Code]
    ,[Bin Type Code]
    ,[Lot No_]
    ,[Registering Date]
from 
    [Warehouse Entry]  
where  
    [Registering Date] <= @DateTo;
```

Comment: is this the complete query ? You have a `ILE` in the `WHERE` clause and I don't see that in the `FROM` at all

Comment: Better to ask this question on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ than here.

Comment: You could partition your table by the `[Registering Date]` field, although it's easier doing it before having there the data, even create an index by that field to speed up your query. Apart from that, you cannot do too much to improve that simple query. This, ommiting what @Squirrel said which is totally true, that the ILE alias used by you is not present anywhere in your query

Comment: Do you have index on `ILE.[Registering Date]` as this is your only one filter? How many rows this query return?

Comment: @Squirrel I edited it.

Comment: @Livius Yes i have inserted all these columns in Index.It returns more than 2 crore rows

Comment: Previously was `ILE.[Registering Date]=` but with `<=` i do not see any way to improve this as i supose you have most data <='2018-08-01'

Comment: can you tell me what does it mean `It returns more than 2 crore rows`?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Do you actually need all those 20 million rows? Or could you aggregate it for your purpose?  And wouldn't something like `where cast([Registering Date] as DATE) between @DateFrom and @DateTo` downsize it more to what you really need? Also, is `[Registering Date]` a DATE or a DATETIME ?

Comment: @Livius That's an Indian word for 20 million. Gaurav Maggoo: please don't use non-english words here.

Comment: @Livius I apologise Sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main problem I think is 20 000 000 records returned from server. Its time costly. Especially, if you are querying "big" data types (xml, binary, etc.), and your server is remote with slow internet connection.

Minor problem is DISTINCT. Youre performing this over all records to be returned to frontend.

NEVER return all dataset to frontend. Use PAGING instead.

Here is way how to do this:

```
--  declare @DateTo as DateTime ='2018-08-01';
--  declare @page_size int = 25;
--  declare @page int = 1;

;with [data] as (
    select distinct 
         [Location Code]
        ,[Bin Code]
        ,[Item No_]
        ,[Quantity]
        ,[Qty_ (Base)]
        ,[Zone Code]
        ,[Bin Type Code]
        ,[Lot No_]
        ,[Registering Date]
    from 
        [Warehouse Entry]  
    where  
        [Registering Date] <= @DateTo
)
select
     [Location Code]
    ,[Bin Code]
    ,[Item No_]
    ,[Quantity]
    ,[Qty_ (Base)]
    ,[Zone Code]
    ,[Bin Type Code]
    ,[Lot No_]
    ,[Registering Date]
from 
    [data]   
order by     
    [Registering Date] asc
offset 
    @page_size * (@page - 1) rows fetch next @page_size rows only;
```

Comment: Fixed the scale, crore is 10 million.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should **show exact query, especially exact where clause**.

> I cannot use any filters as I have to showcase data location wise.

This line is not clear.This line is important to understand.

For 2 crore rows `distinct` matter seriously.

Remove Distinct.

Also why you will fetch so many record at one time.you have to apply Paging.

As per your visible query,

Create non clustered index on Registering Date

```
Create non clustered index ix_Test on [Warehouse Entry]([Registering Date])include( [Location Code]
    ,[Bin Code]
    ,[Item No_]
    ,[Quantity]
    ,[Qty_ (Base)]
    ,[Zone Code]
    ,[Bin Type Code]
    ,[Lot No_]
)
```